Incorrect answer obtained by differentiating through chain rule
The given problem is to find the the derivative of $(\ln x)^{\cos x}$.
I tried to find it using chain rule.  I first differentiated the function with respect to the $\ln x$, yielding $\cos x((\ln x)^{\cos x-1})$, then $\ln x$ wrt $x$, giving $1/x$.  Hence, the answer is $$\frac{\cos x((\ln x)^{\cos x-1})}{x}$$
However, that is  only one of the terms in the solution
The solution is $$((\ln x)^{\cos x})\left[\frac{\cos x}{x} \cdot \ln x−\sin x \ln(\ln x)\right]$$
I understood the steps given in the solution, however, I don't understand why the above method provides an incomplete answer. What is the flaw here?

Welcome to MathSE.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

You are using the chain rule correctly, but the wrong rule overall.  The power rule is only if you have a constant power.  here, you have a power that is a function of $x$.  Therefore, you need to use the generalized power rule (for $u^v$).

This rule is a combination of the power rule and the exponent rule:
$d(u^v) = v,u^{v-1} du + \ln(u)u^v,dv$

Did you express $(\ln x)^{\cos x}$ in the form $e^{\cos x\ln(\ln x)}$?

Note.  The power rule as we know it is an application of the chain rule.  $x^n = e^{n\ln x}$ so $\frac {dx^n}{dx} = \frac {de^{n\ln x}}{d n\ln x}\frac{dn\ln x}{d\ln x}\frac{d\ln x}{dx}=e^{n\ln x}\cdot n\cdot \frac 1x= x^n\cdot \cdot 1x=nx^{n-1}$.

Thanks for the help, everyone! I now understand that I overlooked the fact that the power also varies with x, and the above can only  be applied if the power is constant.

You should write $f(x)$ as
$$f(x)=(\ln x)^{\cos x}=e^{\ln\left((\ln x)^{\cos x}\right)}=e^{(\cos x)(\ln\ln x)}$$
So
\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=e^{(\cos x)(\ln\ln x)}\frac{d}{dx}\left((\cos x)(\ln\ln x)\right)
\\&=e^{(\cos x)(\ln\ln x)}\left((-\sin x)(\ln\ln x)+(\cos x)\frac{1}{\ln x}\frac{1}{x}\right)
\\&=(\ln x)^{\cos x}\left(\frac{\cos x}{x\ln x}-(\sin x)(\ln\ln x)\right)
\end{align*}
As said in the comments, the error comes from the fact that you used the power rule without the power being constant. In these cases you have to transform the expression in an exponential, as we've done in the first line.

You need a multivariable version of the chain rule. You get things like:

The derivative of $x^k$ is $$k \,x^{k-1}.$$

The derivative of $f(x)^k$ is $$k \,f(x)^{k-1}\, f'(x).$$

The derivative of $k^x$ is $$k^x\, \log_e(k).$$

The derivative of $k^{g(x)}$ is $$k^{g(x)}\, \log_e(k)\, g'(x).$$

The derivative of $f(x)\, g(x)$ is $$g(x)\, f'(x) +f(x) \, g'(x).$$

The derivative of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is $$g(x) \,f(x)^{g(x)-1}\, f'(x) +f(x)^{g(x)}\, \log_e(f(x))\, g'(x).$$


The last of these will give your result.

The answer was derived by using logarithmic differentiation, which will make complex functions far, far easier to differentiate.
Say for instance we have $$y = a^x$$  It would be incorrect to use the power rule since $a$ is a constant, so we take the logarithm of each side (I'm using $\ln x$ here)...$$\ln y = x \ln a$$  Now, we differentiate both sides using implicit differentiation for the left and the product rule on the right...$$\dfrac {y'}{y} = x (0) + \ln a (1) = \ln a$$ Now, multiply by $y$ to get $$y' = y \ln a$$ Since $y = a^x$, we have for our derivative $$y' = a^x \ln a$$
In your case, you would let $$y = (\ln x)^{\cos x}$$ and taking logarithms you get $$\ln y = \cos x \ln (\ln x)$$ Take the derivative of both sides, use the product rule on the right, then simplify, and you'll get the answer you want.
It also works with products, such as $y = (2x+7)^2(3x-1)^3(4x+5)^4$, where instead of multiplying out the product, you can take the logs of each side, then the derivatives, and then simplify the result.
